# Draw a circle in a canvas with several gradient colors

Tags: android, canvas, gradient

I need to draw a circle in an Android canvas, based on a gradient list of colors. I managed to draw it without the gradient, as a set of arcs each having one of the colors in the list, as presented by the following image.

[image]

How can I draw it with an actual gradient? I tried with the following code to apply a shader to the paint:

```
Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, circleWidth, circleHeight, colorList, null, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
paint.setShader(shader);
canvas.drawCircle(circleWidth / 2, circleHeight / 2, radius, paint);
```

but the result is as follows.

[image]

Comment: I exactly need this feature in my app.Can you give me full source for this implementation please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I managed to make it using a SweepGradient.

```
Shader shader = new SweepGradient(circleWidth / 2, circleHeight / 2, colorList, null);
paint.setShader(shader);
canvas.drawCircle(circleWidth / 2, circleHeight / 2, radius, paint);
```

[image]