# How to create rounded border with dividers and gradient for all divided parts in Android?

Tags: android, border

I am trying to create a rounded border with 5 dividers/segments that contain gradients **for each divider**.
Attaching reference image(sorry for bad editing images)

[image]

I am able to fill the rounded border around the image with a gradient but I am unable to proceed further with it.

Any help or reference to it will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom view and draw circle with gradient colors in it.

See this answer： https://stackoverflow.com/a/37743507/2173056